# cannot get user currentLocation in android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, android-maps

i am going to show user current location in map but i have following error in onResume()(super.onResume()):

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        **super.onResume();**
        mapView.onResume();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.fk.o()' on a null object reference
```

my class extends following:

```
extends SupportMapFragment implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener
```

onCreateView:

```
mapView=(MapView)view.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        map = mapView.getMap();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mActivity)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
```

override:

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
        else {
            handleNewLocation(location);
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(mActivity, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i("TAG", "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }
    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("I am here!");
        map.addMarker(options);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }
```

i really have no idea about this error, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your **onCreateView()**:

`super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);`

Your **onCreateView()** is useless without it. This is why it's likely that your `mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` is not called.

Make sure you initialize your `mapView` object (`new MapView`), it might be null.